# Can't use onChange property on input file by using useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want customize the input file button so I decided to use `useRef`, but in this situation I cant read file properties. How can I do this?

```
const inputFile = useRef(null);
const onButtonClick = () => {
  inputFile.current.click();
};
return (
  <>
    <ToggleButtonGroup size="small" className={classes.marginEnd}>
      <input
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        // accept=".xls,.xlsx"
        ref={inputFile}
        onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)}
        type="file"
        // onClick={handleInput}
      />
      <Tooltip title="upload">
        <ToggleButton size={"small"}>
          <CloudUpload onClick={onButtonClick}></CloudUpload>
        </ToggleButton>
      </Tooltip>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a codepen to test the same, it worked well for me. Can you try commenting out the `onChange` handler if it works for you? Rest of my code is quite similar to yours. The other issue might be that the `onButtonClick` function is not triggered, if you can put a console log or a debugger to test it out once.

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/jaybhatt21/pen/YzZqeKK) - Click on File Upload button, the popup comes up.

Also, some notes from React JS Documentation about the same - [React docs for File Upload Input](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag)

Comment: thanks so much but my problem is I can not access input file detail with onchange attribute that means when go to the onchange function nothing will happen and because page depend on other state so I dont want to rerender all the page is there any other way to customize the input file ?